# Marketing ROI: Modelling media budget impact on first choice, relevant set (over time)

Tags: r, mixed-model, structural-equation-modeling, marketing

I want to analyze a dataset with longitudinal data collected over three years.

Each month n = 200 randomized people (edit: new sample each month) are asked a small set of evaluative questions (brand assessment, first choice, relevant set etc.). Additionally, there are six media budget values (e.g. for TV, social media and so on) collected each month.

Now, ideally I want to create a path model/ SEM which connects the influence of the monthly media budgets and those assessments (incl. model aspects like: brand assessment influences first choice).

However, I'm not sure, how to connect the budgets with the evaluative questions (e.g. like a treatment variable with a fixed value for everyone in the specific month) and how to account for the longitudinal aspect of the data or just use it as pseudo cross sectional data and roll with it?

In the end, the predictive aspect would be interesting: how does a change in budget influences the change of evaluative items (so unstandardized beta would be useful).

Any input and idea how to model this would be great!

Comment: Is it the same 200 subjects every month, or different subjects ?

Comment: Thanks for the question, this is 200 new subjects every month